# How can i use a reverse shell over global Internet?

Tags: security, ip, reverse-shell

I'm very new to computers and hacking.
The questions I have:

1. How does one use a reverse shell over a global IP?
2. Do I need a server or will my pc/Raspberry Pi running on my router work?
3. Our Router has a dynamic IP, but it doesn't change often. Might this cause trouble?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Lucky_Star, you may also be new to the [se] network. These kind of non-programming questions are better asked at [su]. As for your questions: have you tried? In principle any kind of connection can be used, as long as you can establish the socket. I'm not sure which is the terminal client and which one the terminal server from your question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1. How does one use a reverse shell over a global IP?`

You need to host a listener on your device, then your need to port forward your router to allow the listener to be publicly accessible.

`2. Do I need a server or will my pc/Raspberry Pi running on my router work?`

Any pc/raspberry pi is fine. Only thing to note is that the reverse shell will only accept connections if the device is turned on.

`3. Our Router has a dynamic IP, but it doesn't change often. Might this cause trouble?`

If your router's public IP address changes, then all your currently deployed clients will stop working. Either be prepared to remake them each time it changes, or setup dynamic DNS for your router and use that to create your binaries.